# Need to Upload mht file format to wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, http, mhtml

I have some '.mht' files.  I need to upload that file in to my word press site. but when i upload that files, its showing "HTTP ERROR"  Error.

Is there any other way to upload '.mht' files to word press site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Upload Additional File Types To Your WordPress Blog using the below code here.

```
 <?php
 add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
 function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes = array() ) {
 // add your extension to the array
 $existing_mimes['ppt'] = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
 // or: $existing_mimes['ppt|pot|pps'] = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
 // to add multiple extensions for the same mime type
 // add as many as you like
 // removing existing file types
 unset( $existing_mimes['exe'] );
 // add as many as you like
 // and return the new full result
 return $existing_mimes;
 }
 ?>
```

So you can add your file formats in this way by using the above code
For more info Regarding this issue visit this [link](http://www.binaryturf.com/upload-additional-file-types-wordpress-blog/)..
Default file formats that supports for word press is [here](http://en.support.wordpress.com/accepted-filetypes/)..

Answer (score 0):

add this in your function.php

```
function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes=array() ) {

    $existing_mimes['mht'] = 'multipart/related';

    return $existing_mimes;

}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
```